# How to fix ppa-purge error Release '<distribution>' for '<package>' was not found

Tags: ubuntu, apt

[ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge) is a nice tool that [may save your configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309966/difference-between-ppa-purge-and-add-apt-repository-r) if you have install a ppa that messed with your system by installing new packages that you didn't want.

Unfortunately, ppa-purge didn't work for me because I'm using a distribution that updated `lsb_release` (in my case elementary freya).

Here's the error messages that I got:

```
...
E: Release 'freya' for 'gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0' was not found
E: Release 'freya' for 'gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0' was not found
E: Release 'freya' for 'gstreamer1.0-alsa' was not found
...
Unable to find an archive "freya" for the package "gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0"
Unable to find an archive "freya" for the package "gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0"
Unable to find an archive "freya" for the package "gstreamer1.0-alsa"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call ppa-purge as follow:

```
ppa-purge -d <release> <ppa you want to be removed>
```

So elementary freya being based on ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) I had to call:

```
ppa-purge -d trusty <ppa you want to be removed>
```

And after a while, everything was A-Okay.

*I love you ppa-purge*